# Problem with custom font feature for addition kerning in OpenType font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, superscripts, kerning, opentype

I try to add some custom kerning to an OpenType font used with `fontspec` under `lualatex`. The real-world example uses the `Brill` fonts, but as they are not part of TeX Live I use `Libertinus` in the example below.

I want to add some kerning between specific characters with diacritics and superscript numbers. The only combination which works is the direct usage of the unicode superscript numbers. As soon as I use `\textsuperscript`, which is redefined by `realscripts` to use the correct figures, the extra kerning is not applied.

Is there any way to achieve what I want while using `\textsuperscript`?

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% Values below are for demonstration purposes only
\directlua {
   fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
      name = "supkern",
      type = "kern",
      data = {
         ["ī"] = {
            ["¹"] = 500,%
            ["two.sups"] = 500,%
         },
         ["š"] = {%
            ["one.sups"] = 500,%
            ["two.sups"] = 500,%
         },
      },
   }
}
\usepackage[defaultfeatures={RawFeature={+supkern}}]{libertinus} %Brill in real life
\usepackage{realscripts}

\begin{document}
   ī\textsuperscript{12}
   
   ī¹
   
   ī{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}2}
   
   {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+supkern}}ī\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}12}
   
   š\textsuperscript{2}
   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The realscripts code adds an \addfontfeature command. And this basically means that you have two different fonts. Something like this should work, but one should add some tests, so that is doesn't fail if a font doesn't have the superscripts. Look in the realscript code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% Values below are for demonstration purposes only
\directlua {
   fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
      name = "supkern",
      type = "kern",
      data = {
         ["ī"] = {
            ["¹"] = 500,%
            ["two.sups"] = 500,%
         },
         ["š"] = {%
            ["one.sups"] = 500,%
            ["two.sups"] = 500,%
         },
      },
   }
}
\usepackage[defaultfeatures={RawFeature={+sups,+supkern}}]{libertinus} %Brill in real life
\RenewDocumentCommand\textsuperscript{m}{#1}
\begin{document}
   ī\textsuperscript{12}

ī¹ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrike for the explanation. I looked at the `realscripts` code, but thought, that adding the feature `VerticalPosition=Superior` wouldn't create a new font internally.

Comment: As far as I can see, `one.sups` and the other `.sups` have to be replaced with the Unicode glyphs in the definition of the new feature.

Comment: In my real-world problem I do of course have normal numbers as well, not only superscript numbers. So setting the `sups` feature globally is not what I want. Moreover if I want to use the old definition of `\textsuperscript` as well (similiar to `\textsuperscript*` defined by `realscripts`) I need to add some more complex definitions I guess. Anyway, thanks again for your answer, which shows me the correct path to follow.